# Passing XAML Window Type to a function

Tags: c#, types

I have a function that is designed to create an instance of a window and return me a `RelayCommand` (basically, it's just an MVVMLite helper method:

```
public static RelayCommand NavigateTo(Type navigateTo)
{
    var relayCmd = new RelayCommand (() => Navigate(navigateTo));
    return relayCmd;
}

private static void Navigate(Type navigateTo)
{
    var newWin = Activator.CreateInstance(navigateTo);
    ((Window)newWin).Show();
}
```

I then call this in a separate class like this:

```
this.MyCommand = Navigation.NavigateTo(View.MyView);
```

MyView is a valid Window, however, I get the following compile error:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'MyProject.Navigation.NavigateTo(System.Type)' has some invalid arguments
```

I can make it work, by doing this:

```
this.MyCommand = Navigation.NavigateTo(typeof(View.MyView));
```

My question is: why?  I'm passing a type and expecting a type.  Also, is there a way that I can get my `NavigateTo` function to simply accept the class name of the Window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that what I wanted was to use generics, which allows me to pass the class type and deal with it in the function:

```
    public static RelayCommand NavigateTo<T>()
    {
        Type dest = typeof(T);
        var relayCmd = new RelayCommand(() => Navigate(dest));
        return relayCmd;
    }

    private static void Navigate<T>()
    {
        object dest = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();            
        ((Window)dest).Show();            
    }
```

And call like this:

```
this.MyCommand = Navigation.NavigateTo<MyView>();
```

Comment: Fun thing is that I've just recently answered with a similar statically-typed navigation for Windows Phone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004086/is-there-a-typesafe-way-of-navigating-between-screens-in-windows-phone/20063659#20063659

Answer (score 1):

> I'm passing a type and expecting a type.

You try to pass a **type**, but you cannot do this in .Net. You can only pass `System.Type` **objects**.
You can get a `System.Type` object from class, by writing `typeof(MyClass)`.
You can get a `System.Type` object from object, by writing `obj.GetType()`.

You need to understand the difference between **class** / **type** and **object** / **instance**.

Comment: I'll assign the bounty as this is the highest votes answer, but see my answer, as this is possible using generics

Comment: @pm_2 Yes, your answer is better. I didn't quite get your context >_<

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using typeof to pass the type otherwise you are passing a class. The typeof grabs the System.Type which is what you are expecting, otherwise it is looking for a definition in that class. You could also use .GetType().

Comment: How can I pass `View.MyView` without using `typeof()` or `.GetType()`?

Comment: I honestly don't think you can. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/58918ffs.aspx. You are asking for a System.Type. If you try to just pass in View.MyView you are passing in a 'type' but you are passing in a System.Type.